# Настройка переменных PATH для Laravel

Tags: консоль, laravel5, path

Использую OSPanel (он же Open server)/win10. Через composer установил laravel 5.х, всё работает норм, проекты создает без проблем. Но куда удобней создавать проекты через `laravel new Name`, не так ли? 
Так вот, с этим возникла проблема. Win10 (но это не точно, не знаю что(/кто?) конкретно "мешает видеть" файл) просто не видит исполняемый laravel файл.

При наборе в консоли `laravel new Name` появляется ошибка: `"laravel" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.` Но, если прописать путь вручную: `"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\laravel" new Name` 
то всё отлично работает, без ошибок. 
В переменных средах путь прописан, но толку от этого ноль:
[image: переменные среды]

Помогите справиться с проблемой!

---

OSPanel Modules:

HTTP => Apache-php-7.2-x64

PHP => php-7.2-x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените свой путь в переменной среды на этот:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\laravel`

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Comment: Ради интереса и на ПК то же самое делал с вин 7 - проблема сохранется, поставил на виртуалку ubuntu - та же проблема.. хм

Comment: сам исполняемый файл laravel.exe в этой папке?

Comment: Я ещё в теме написал что если писать путь вручную для команды то всё ОК.
Полагаю, это значит что все файлы на месте, и да - всё на месте.

Comment: попробуйте проверить целостность системных файлов , запустите в консоли от администратора sfc /scannow и скажите какой результат.

Comment: странно что на разных системах у вас одна ошибка, как вы устанавливаете фреймворк?

Comment: Защита ресурсов Windows не обнаружила нарушений целостности.
Ставлю как: 
1. обновил composer (php composer.phar self-update) 
2. скачал сам laravel (composer global require "laravel/installer")
Всё проходит без ошибок. 
Если надо - в PATH добавляю нужные директивы..
Если создавать через composer (composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel name) то всё ОК, и аналогично если в команде laravel new blog заменять laravel на путь к исп. файлу

Comment: Поставил на винду с нуля php, apache, mysql, composer, и, о, чудо! Всё заработало. Полагаю, дело в самом OSPanel, буду писать на их форум.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите использовать команду "laravel new"  в терминале OSPanel (он же Open server), нужно в настройках OSPanel выбрать Свой Path + Win Path [image: Настройки OSPanel]
Я указываю путь к композеру который в самом OSPanel (D:\Program Files\OSPanel\userdata\composer\vendor\bin).

Можно вообще отказаться от использования Windows PATH.
Создать свой файл path.txt(UTF-8) В папке "...\OSPanel\userdata\config".
[image: Без Win PATH]